# Select-String -Pattern Output when piping into

Tags: powershell, debugging, pipe, select-string

I try to get PowerShell to spit out a Semantic Versioning Variable but get stuck in it displaying just the command I entered (doing that in the ISE) or either of 2 errors ('missing argument' or 'doesn't accept piped input'), which, if I try to resolve them, end in the command simply being displayed again.

How do I get this:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://someplace).Links.href | Out-String -Stream |
    Select-String -Pattern [regex]$someGoodRegex -OutVariable $NodeVersion_target
```

assuming the regex and web request point to solid things to simply stick the searched term in the `-OutVariable` defined?

---

On a more general note, is there a good way to display the properties of the objects in the pipe? After a great deal of digging, I stumbled upon `{$_}` but can't get it to display anything but the command again if the command gets a little more complex that just a simple cmdlet.

Comment: I'm still fidgeting around with it and can't get it to output something meaningful. The following lines may express more what I'm looking for: `(Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://nodejs.org/dist/latest) | Select Links.href.ToString | Select-String -Pattern "v\d+\.\d+\.\d+/s" -OutVariable $NodeVer_target `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `[regex]`. `Select-String` already treats the argument to the parameter `-Pattern` as a regular expression.

Remove the `$` from the variable name. You need it to use a variable directly, but the `-OutVariable` parameter expects the bare variable name without the leading `$`.

You can also remove the `Out-String -Stream`.

Something like this should work:

```
$uri = 'http://www.example.com/'
$re  = 'v\d+\.\d+\.\d+/s'
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri).Links.href |
    Select-String -Pattern $re -OutVariable NodeVersion_target
```

Alternatively you can assign the output of the pipeline to a variable instead of using `-OutVariable`:

```
$uri = 'http://www.example.com/'
$re  = 'v\d+\.\d+\.\d+/s'
$NodeVersion_target = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri).Links.href |
                      Select-String -Pattern $re
```

The latter is actually more PoSh.

---

As for inspecting the current object in a pipeline: pipe into [`Get-Member`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) to get a list of the properties/methods of the pipelined objects, and pipe into [`Format-List *`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list) to get a list of the values of the pipelined objects.